# Django CMS logo change

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Is there a way to change the Django CMS logo, for my own company logo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace /media/cms/images/cms_toolbar.png

Or edit the #cms_toolbar definition in the media/cms/css/toolbar.css stylesheet.

Comment: thanks guys, i have changed it successfully, turns out i had to do it from the base.html template

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the logo has been replaced by an "icon" in a specific django-cms-font. Using Django CMS 3.2 version you can turn it off by adding

```
div.cms .cms-toolbar-item-logo a:before {
    display: none;
}
```

to your site's custom `.css` file. If you want to replace it by something else use

```
div.cms .cms-toolbar-item-logo a:before {
    content: "something else";
}
```

Remember to load your site's custom css after the `{% renderblock css %}` tag or django CMS's css definition will overwrite yours.

Answer (score 1):

Which logo do you mean?

I think logo is just an image inside the template, right?

Check out the template in `cms/templates/cms/new.html`

Comment: the logo that appears in the top left corner of the admin page, and says Django CMS, i went to the file you said and changed it, but nothing happened

Comment: Then you should check out the admin templates. Especially any that would defind a {% block branding %}, maybe you have it there?

Answer (score 0):

It's located inside the `djangocms_admin_style` module, the path is `djangocms_admin_style/static/djanogcms_admin_style/img/django-cms-logo.png`. It's better to clone it, customize it and then simply add it to your project under the 
`INSTALLED_APPS=[]`.